# maximum value in float

Tags: c, floating-point

For the following loop, I was expecting output to be `sum = 20e6` but the output is `sum = 1.67772e+07`.

```
float sum=0.0f;
for(i=0;i<20e6;i++)
    sum = sum + 1.0f;
printf("sum = %g\n", sum);
```

**Question 1:** Why `sum` being float cannot hold values greater than `1.67772e07`?

**Question 2:** If I change the statement in the loop to `sum = sum + 1.001f;` then final value of sum is `2.32229e+07`. Why is this difference in the value of sum?

**Question 3:** Can we control this behaviour in the loop above such that we can use float for values bigger than `1.67772e07` while still incrementing by 1.0f?

Comment: What is the type of i?

Comment: Because floating point numbers are evil.  You should read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You can check the maximum available using [`std::numeric_limits<float>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's not a matter of the maximum representable value, but of roundoff error.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm well aware of this, just wanted to give the information.

Comment: Because `1.f + 1.67772e07` is still `1.67772e07` due to precision.

Comment: Change type from `float` to `double` if you need more precision.

Comment: on systems with 32-bit single precision IEEE-754 float, there's 24 bits of precision, so any integer less than 2^24 = 16777216 can be expressed exactly. Outside that range only some integers can be stored

Comment: That's why there is a rule "use double, not float, unless you can give a very good reason why float is better".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At some point, the closest representable value to `x + 1.0f` is `x` itself.  After that point is reached, due to this rounding error your loop won't cause any further increase in `sum`.

As an illustration, you can observe this effect using scientific notation with a fixed number of significant figures.  For example, with 4 significant figures:

```
    0 = 0.000e0
    1 = 1.000e0
    2 = 2.000e0
    3 = 3.000e0
```

...

```
    9 = 9.000e0
   10 = 1.000e1
   11 = 1.100e1
```

...

```
  99 = 9.900e1
 100 = 1.000e2
 101 = 1.010e2
```

...

```
  999 = 9.990e2
 1000 = 1.000e3
 1001 = 1.001e3
```

...

```
 9999 = 9.999e3
10000 = 1.000e4
```

and if you add one more, you should get `1.0001e4`, but since only 4 significant digits are preserved, the stored value is `1.000e4`, e.g. 10000 + 1 = 10000 in this system, and continuing to increment just repeats this calculation forever without changing the result.

Your code works exactly the same way, except that `float` uses binary floating-point, not decimals as scientific notation does.  But the number of significant binary digits is still limited, and when adding one more doesn't change one of those significant digits, `sum` ceases to increase.

It's somewhat more complicated, because with binary, the "correct" result is midway between two representable numbers, so rounding could either occur downward *or upward*, in which case you asked to add 1 but actually get a result 2 higher.  In any case, once the distance between representable values becomes 4, trying to add one will have no effect.

Comment: In order to make my question clearer, I have edited and broken it down into three sub-questions, so can you please address these questions?

Comment: My explanation already covers all three of your sub questions.

Comment: I still cannot understand why incrementing sum with `1.001` keeps on changing sum after `1.67772e07` but incrementing sum with 1.0 does not?

Comment: My last paragraph explains the effect of rounding up.